# PHP: How to use the form type Select Menu in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, list, select

My input type text is working fine.

```
  <textarea rows='3' cols='30' name='comments' onclick='make_blank();'>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) echo $_POST['comments']; ?>
  </textarea>
```

However, once  I try to create a select list menu (BELOW) it does not work.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['package'])) echo $_POST['package'];?>
</select>
```

Help would be appreciated.
Many Thanks!

Comment: Your `select` needs a `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Your select doesn't have the `name` attribute:

```
<select name="package">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
 if(isset($_POST['package'])) echo "<option>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: also " echo "</select></td>
            </tr>" need to be removed

Comment: <tr>
  <select name="package">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 if(isset($_POST['package'])) echo "<option>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>";
 
          </tr>

Comment: add php it seems you don't have php open

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['package'])) echo "<option>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>"; ?>

Comment: There is 2 syntax syntax errors at <select name="package">

Comment: and finally at: if(isset($_POST['package'])) echo "<option>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>";

Comment: same thing + I do have the </php opened

Comment: @user3478096, your php using is incorrect... not need echo every HTML entity, simple end php block: `<?php ... ?><div>Content</div><?php`